# Is ArcGIS archiving based on ObjectID or GlobalID?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, objectid, archiving, global-id

My question is about the "archive" functionality that is available for the enterprise geodatabase tables in ArcMap.

Does it use the ObjectID to determine that an object is the same as an archived one?

Or does it use the GlobalID?

Or is it possible to use any of them?

Do you have any documentation on the subject? I was hoping to find something in [ESRI's Archiving documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/the-archive-process.htm), but I had no luck.

I believe this question is pretty much version and platform independent, but if you think differently, let me know and I can provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Archiving documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/enabling-archiving.htm) only shows an ObjectID column. GlobalID columns are not required for archiving operation ([as they are for replication](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/preparing-data-for-replication.htm)), so it seems that the registered rowid column (which techically isn't required to be 'ObjectID') is the primary key.

You could use either ObjectID or GlobalID on a join if the UUID column was present, but the UUID join would be *much* slower, based on a much wider key and fragmented (randomized) key order.

Comment: I wasn't expecting an answer anymore! Thank you. Back then I found similar info [here](http://www.blairservices.net/case-studies/arcgis-archiving-part-3/), but it is unofficial.